# Detect if google map marker is placed on route

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to detect if a marker is placed in the middle of a route I made using Google Maps API V3?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the middle"?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `isLocationOnEdge`-method of [google.maps.geometry.poly](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#poly)

Note: the geometry-library isn't loaded by default, you must load the library by adding the libraries-parameter to the  maps-API-script-url:   **`&libraries=geometry`**

Comment: That's exactly that what I'm trying to find ,thank you very much! :)